# How to copy a range to another worksheet with for each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a range to an another worksheet and to insert before it 2 columns on the new worksheet. It doesn't copy the original range.

It works, if I copy to the same worksheet.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sh2")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sh3")
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

rowNum = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each row In ws.Range("A1:A" & rowNum)
    ws2.Range("A1:A" & rowNum).Offset(0, 0).Value2 = wb.Name
    ws2.Range("A1:A" & rowNum).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = ws.Name
Next row

For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
    cell.Offset(10, 2).Value2 = cell.Value2
Next cell
```

I expect the column "A" contains the name of active workbook, the "B" the name of active worksheet, the other rows comes the original content. Now, the filename and worksheet's name copied to the new worksheet, but the content not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction you're headed with your code is close, hopefully this example can help. But first, please [always use Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-) in your code.

In setting up your initial variables for the worksheets, using more descriptive variable names makes it more clear exactly which variable is intended to hold certain data. My example set up then is

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim srcWS As Worksheet
Dim dstWS As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set srcWS = wb.Sheets("Sh2")
Set dstWS = wb.Sheets("Sh3")
```

Next, you can create a variable to determine the range area of your source data:

```
Dim srcRange As Range
Set srcRange = srcWS.UsedRange
```

In the case where you want to create your first two columns to contain the workbook and worksheet names, you don't actually need a loop. By creating a `Range` of the size you need, a single statement will place the same value in all of the cells in that range. Therefore you can create your name columns in two statements using

```
dstWS.Range("A1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, 1) = wb.Name
dstWS.Range("B1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, 1) = srcWS.Name
```

I'll establish a destination range that starts in the third column, just to the right of the two name columns:

```
Dim dstRange As Range
Set dstRange = dstWS.Range("C1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, _
                                        srcRange.Columns.Count)
```

Then with the same idea, you can also copy the entire source range to your destination in a single statement as well:

```
dstRange.Value = srcRange.Value
```

And you're done.

Here is the whole example in a single block:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMyRange()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim dstWS As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = wb.Sheets("Sh2")
    Set dstWS = wb.Sheets("Sh3")

    Dim srcRange As Range
    Set srcRange = srcWS.UsedRange

    dstWS.Range("A1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, 1) = wb.Name
    dstWS.Range("B1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, 1) = srcWS.Name

    Dim dstRange As Range
    Set dstRange = dstWS.Range("C1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, _
                                            srcRange.Columns.Count)
    dstRange.Value = srcRange.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: PeterT, how could I edit this code, if I would like to use it with more workbooks and worksheets? So I have more workbooks (within more worksheets per workbooks) and I would like to collect these original worksheets to a new, single worksheet. Currently, my code opens the workbooks, imports the worksheets to an another single worksheet, but copies the same place, not to below each other. Thank you in advance for your answer.